# Word formatting - need to align left to left, right to right in same line

Tags: microsoft-word-2010

I have several lines with text in Word 2010. (in different areas).

I need the left side to align to the left side of the page, and the right side to align to the right side of the page. Can I do this manually somehow?

I tried using the 'justified' formatting but it makes the left side aligned to the left, but the right side isn't aligned to the right.

I'd like to avoid using a table if possible.

```
Some text to float on left side 1                                 some right text 1
Some text to float on left side 2                                 some right text 2
```

Comment: It's a bit unclear what you wish to achieve. Could you explain a bit further, perhaps adding some samples (screenshots)?

Comment: i'm actually doing some formatting for my resume. the company name should align left and the dates should align on the right.

Answer (score 61):

Here's your text in Word.  The tab control is circled.

[image]

**Step 1** - Click the tab control until you see the right tab symbol which looks like a backwards **L**.

**Step 2** - Type a Tab where you want the text to split.

**Step 3** - Click in the ruler at the right end to insert a right tab in the current paragraph.

[image]

In the illustration, the tab is not all the way to the right so you can more easily see it.  You can drag the tab along the ruler to position it anywhere you want - in your case, even with the end of the line as indicated by the white area.

A right tab "anchors" the right end of the text that follows the tab character.  By clicking the tab control, you can choose left, right, or center tabs.  Experiment by inserting different tabs in the ruler and moving them around to see the effect on the text.

Comment: This answer is also useful in LibreOffice.

Comment: Dave's answer is misleading. His step "3" actually comes second in chronological order, *then* you insert the tab. Otherwise, it's just an "ordinary" tab, equivalent to about 11-12 spaces.

Comment: @Logan - Not true.  If you have no specific tabs set and you type a tab, it assumes the default - what you call ordinary.  Then when you specify a right tab (step 3), your newly entered tab becomes the right tab.  You can change the tab type or position after you have typed the tab in the text and it will follow the changes.

Comment: I tried in LibreOffice and it works.

Comment: This "solution" does not adjust automatically when I later change the page margins.

Comment: Actually, the tab does adjust automatically to changes in the page margin.  Tabs are set at a specific point on the page, relative to the left margin.  Move the left margin in and the tab moves with it, maintaining the same distance.  Move the right margin in and the tab doesn't move, unless there is not enough room, then it moves in (left) also.

Don't confuse the paragraph margin with the page margin.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a specific spot where the text "breaks", add a Right Aligned Tab at the right margin. Then insert a Tab where you want the alignment to break.

Comment: how do i insert a right aligned tab & the tab where I want the alignment to break?

Comment: You click the tab type you want from the upper left corner at the intersection of the horizontal and vertical rulers and click on the horizontal ruler where you want the tab stop.

Comment: Sorry for the delay.  See Dave Becker's answer, it has more in-depth info on what I suggested.