# Word formatting - Align left, center, and right in same line

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010

I have lines of text in Word 2010 in which I want to have text aligned on the left, center, and right sides of the page.

[A previous question](https://superuser.com/questions/484261/word-formatting-need-to-align-left-to-left-right-to-right-in-same-line) details how to align to the left and right sides of the page, but I haven't been able to figure out how to also have a section in the middle.

```
Some text to float on left side 1       center text 1                    some right text 1
Some text to float on left side 2       center text 2                    some right text 2
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Keep clicking the tab button left to the ruler till you are in a symbol looking like a flipped T.

Click on the mid in the ruler where you like to position the middle text. You'll use key tab to do so.